# Копирование файлов на множество серверов

Tags: linux, bash, автоматизация, scp

Сейчас у меня 20 серверов + 1 главный. С главного я с помощью scp скидываю файлы на все другие.

Как автоматизировать процесс, чтобы один файл можно было залить на свой список серверов?

---

Сейчас я делаю так:

```
$ scp package.rpm user@server2:/tmp/
```

и так с 20 серверами.

Comment: и можно как-то сразу задать пароль чтобы не вводить по 100 раз одно и тоже?

Comment: Если просто и последовательно, пишете скрипт на [expect](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). В принципе, там  для передачи пароля в scp/ssh нужен псевдотерминал (ну, и анализ вывода scp), что и предоставляет expect.

Comment: Как вариант настроить rpm-репозиторий. Также для задач автоматизации **крайне рекомендую** Ansible.

Comment: спасибо, буду поглощать новые технологии. expect проманю.

Comment: Очень сильно зависит от того, что кроется за "скидываю файлы на другие сервера". Если это подразумевает "то конфиг http на все серверы прокинуть, то конфиг mysql обновить на серверах" -- то вам прямая дорога изучать ansible.

Comment: Если это подразумевает, что "у меня есть папка, её нужно скопировать один-в-один на все сервера" -- то логично посмотреть в сторону git: один репозиторий и двадцать копий, можно обновлять их массово одним скриптом или постхуком.

Comment: Подозреваю, что если вы копируете rpm-пакет, то следом вы его устанавливаете и конфигурируете. Верно? Как у вас эта часть устроена?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос синхронизации между хостами не решается в одну строчку. Опишу общие принцыпы, так как конкретная настройка будет обширна в описании.

Было несколько путей, которые я испробовал на хостах (3.000+): писать скрипты в ручную, создовать демонов синхронизации, использовать готовые решения.

Для отпраки использовал протоколы ssh, http[s] и torrent, последий позволяет создать свою отказоустойчивую сеть передачии контента.

От простого к запутанному

У вас локальная сеть, без каких либо ограничений. Хосты и сервер на Linux. Можно поднять веб сервер.  с lsftp для раздачи файлов. Связка pxe+apache+lsftp отлично отрабатывает свою задачу уже два года. Цеклично запустить. на каждом

```
~$ wget file_server:/file
```

в этом варианте вообще не нужны ключи для хостов и пароли для ftp, достаточно иметь удаленный доступ к кажому. Парадигма pull

У вас разрозненные хосты, доступ к которым идет через общую сеть (intrnet, WAN, MAN или VPN).  В наличие ssh сервер-клиент на каждом из хостов и основном сервере. В этом варианте выгодней по скорости использовать **rsync** и **expect** если нет RSA ключей то на сервере пишем небольшой скрипт на expect

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

hosts="$1"
send_file="$2"

for host in "$hosts"; do
    expect -c "
         spawn rsync -az --append \"$send_file\" \"$host\"
         expect \".assword.+\"
         send \"my_password\r\"
    " &
done
```

с ключамии в одну строчку

```
~# while read -r host; do rsync -az --append /path/to/file "$host" & done < hosts
```

Интересный момент - это отсылать каждую "раздачу" в фоновый процесс &.

Вы хотите синхронизировать тысячи и болелее хостов или узлов кластера. Тут уже скриптами не справишся из готовых и бесплатных решений можно отметить:

- Ansible - модули copy и synchronize. ssh протокол
- Lsyncd (Live Syncing Daemon) синхронизирует локальные директории с удаленными хостами. Обертка rsync демонизированная на Lua
- Resilio решение для распределенной доставки файлов.
- glusterfs расспределеная файловая система
- libtorrent открытая библиотека на c++  смотрите приложения использующие ее в качестве базовой, на оффициальном сайте.

Answer (score 10):

Всяк сверчок хвалит свой шесток. Я буду хвалить Ansible. Он использует обычное SSH-соединение с теми же настройками, которые используются при обычном `ssh hostname`

Предположим, что вы уже настроили доступ по SSH-ключам.

Перечисляем хосты в файле `hosts` (имя произвольное). Можно и параметром задавать, но предполагаю, что список хостов у вас более-менее постоянный.

```
host1.dc1
host2.dc1
# все номера с 1 по 10
host[1:10].dc2
```

В любом месте запускаем команду.

```
ansible all -i path/to/hosts -m copy -a 'src=path/to/example.txt dest=/tmp/example.txt'
```

И всё, файлы копируются, а вы получаете отчёт по каждому хосту:

```
example.host | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": true, 
    "checksum": "c3499c2729730a7f807efb8676a92dcb6f8a3f8f", 
    "dest": "/tmp/example.txt", 
    "gid": 1002, 
    "group": "root", 
    "md5sum": "1a79a4d60de6718e8e5b326e338ae533", 
    "mode": "0664", 
    "owner": "root", 
    "size": 7, 
    "src": "/home/username/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1467312219.54-140783443033936/source", 
    "state": "file", 
    "uid": 1002
}
```

Дополнительные параметры здесь: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html

Если не настроили SSH-ключи, то к строке запуска добавим:

```
-u <имя-пользователя> --ask-pass
```

Тогда соединение будет устанавливаться по указанному имени пользователя, пароль будет запрошен в командной строке.

Comment: а если пользователи разные, есть штатное средство их указать? или хотя бы `~/.ssh/config` будет приниматься во внимание?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin разумеется, используется стандартный SSH со стандартными настройками на текущей машине, в частности  `~/.ssh/config`.

Answer (score 9):

### с ключами

я бы рекомендовал воспользоваться возможностью авторизации по ключу.

1. сгенерируйте себе пару публичный/секретный ключ:

   ```
   $ ssh-keygen
   ```

   на все вопросы можно ответить «утвердительно» (нажать <kbd>enter</kbd>).
   если ключ уже существует — ничего страшного не произойдёт, программа сообщит об этом и предложит перезаписать файлы (от чего можно отказаться, нажав <kbd>n</kbd> и <kbd>enter</kbd>).
2. скопируйте публичную часть ключа на все нужные серверы:

   ```
   $ ssh-copy-id user@host
   ```
3. установите программу `parallel-scp` (в debian-основных дистрибутивах она обычно входит в состав пакета *pssh* и переименована из оригинального имени `pscp` для избежания конфликта имён с программой из пакета *putty-tools*, имеющей совсем иную функциональность).
4. копируйте файл:

   ```
   $ parallel-scp -H user1@host1 -H user2@host2 /локальный/файл /путь/на/удалённой/машине
   [1] 18:40:23 [SUCCESS] user2@host2
   [2] 18:40:24 [SUCCESS] user1@host1
   ```

   `/путь/на/удалённой/машине` должен быть абсолютным, а путь к локальному файлу — не обязательно (может быть относительным).

   опций `-H user@host` может быть произвольное (разумное) количество.

   более того — ­имеет смысл вместо них указывать опцию `-h /путь/к/списку`, где `/путь/к/списку` — файл, содержащий строки формата `[user@]host[:port]` (в некоторых реализациях — `host[:port] [user]`, уточните в справке к вашей версии: `man parallel-scp`).

если нет возможности установить упомянутую программу, воспользуйтесь советом из [ответа @sercxjo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/540135/178576).

### без ключей

если по какой-то причине вы не можете/хотите пользоваться доступом по ключу, то, чтобы не вводить пароль на запрос программы *ssh/scp*, можете воспользоваться, например, программой `sshpass` (обычно — из одноимённого пакета):

```
$ sshpass -p 'пароль' scp параметры-программы-scp
$ sshpass -p 'пароль' ssh параметры-программы-ssh
```

модифицировать соответствующим образом скрипт, предложенный @sercxjo, я думаю, труда не составит.

---

полезная информация: [Одновременное управление несколькими серверами](http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/admin/pdsh_parallel.html)

Comment: Не знаю, как у ТС, а у нас один из клиентов уперто не желает такого механизма на своей более чем сотни серверов.

Comment: @avp, «такого» — это какого?

Comment: Распространения ключей, т.е. возможности входа без явного ввода пароля.

Comment: @avp, *Распространения ключей* — а вторая часть моего ответа тогда — про что?

Comment: @avp, кстати, возможно, ваш клиент не в курсе, что даже сам openssh [поддерживает подпись и отзыв ключей (т.н. сертификацию)](https://ef.gy/hardening-ssh), не говоря уже про всякие надстройки типа ldap, и, возможно, ваш клиент не знает ни про парольную защиту секретных ключей, ни про *ssh-agent* (и его возможность хранения расшифрованных секретных ключей лишь на указанный промежуток времени).

Comment: Да, `sshpass` решает задачу ТС с `scp` (Но не нашу с `ssh`, когда  иногда надо вводить 2 пароля. К тому же в некоторых случаях (насколько помню на медленных каналах) она (`sshpass`) неуверенно соединяется).

Comment: Не знаю, о чем его безопасники в курсе, а о чем нет, со мной они это не обсуждали. Вынесли когда-то решение и уперлись.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, я читал новость и обсуждение на [opennet-е](http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=44659) и [lor-е](https://www.linux.org.ru/news/opensource/12694144)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, к слову: вы решили «добить» группу бэ? (сужу по поступающим нотификациям).

Comment: Давайте продолжим [в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41970/discussion-on-answer-by-alexander-barakin-----).

Answer (score 3):

Настройте [ssh-авторизацию по ключу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ssh%20%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D1%83).

Пример скрипта для параллельной закачки, если user и пути закачки на всех серверах одинаковые (`$1` - первый аргумент при запуске скрипта):

```
#!/bin/bash
serverlist=server1 server2 server3
for server in $serverlist ; do
    scp "$1" user@$server:/tmp/ &
done
wait
```

Comment: Это может быть полезной информацией для автора поста (если он ручками каждый раз вводит ключ, бррр!!) или он в курсе такой возможности и спокойно ходит по серверам с форвардом агента в сессии.

Comment: а зачем второй цикл? одной команды *wait* более чем достаточно: *`help wait`:If ID is not given, waits for all currently active child processes*

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вы правы, когда-то сталкивался с другим поведением, но видимо это было очень давно

Answer (score 3):

Вот, смотрю, пока конкретной помощи нет, набросал что-то (вроде работающее) на коленке:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Test scp-expect
User=avp
PASS=XXXXXX
RDIR=/tmp
FILE=$1
if [ "X$FILE" == "X" ]; then
    echo usage: ./tscp FILE
    exit 1
fi

echo Go...

#rm ~/.ssh/known_hosts  вместо этого -o 'UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null' в вызове scp

for HOST in nas
do
    expect -c "
spawn scp -o UserKnownHostsFile\\ /dev/null $FILE $User@$HOST:$RDIR
expect \".*no)? \"
send \"yes\r\"
expect \".*assword:\"
send \"$PASS\r\"
expect eof
"
done
```

В данном случае один файл пересылается на один хост (с именем nas) в оглавление /tmp.

Обратите внимание, для упрощения скрипта `expect` я делаю недоступной всю локальную информацию `ssh` о хостах (по умолчанию она находится в ~/.ssh/known_hosts), поскольку при запуске неизвестно, на данный хост уже заходили ssh/scp или еще нет (и тогда `scp` требует ввода "yes").

Ну, думаю, как тут работает [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) в принципе ясно, а шелловскую обвязку (что, откуда, куда, где брать пароль и т.п.) Вы сами под свою задачу напишите.

Comment: 1. *rm ~/.ssh/known_hosts* — зачем удалять все сохранённые идентификаторы хостов? 2. один пользователь и пароль для всех сайтов? 3. громоздкий expect вместо отлично работающих: и механизма авторизации по ключу и программы `sshpass`?

Comment: предолжение удалять `~/.ssh/known_hosts` — деструктивно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, "`зачем удалять все сохранённые идентификаторы хостов?`"  -- это самое простое решение для подобного скрипта. Для постоянной работы, согласен, не хорошо. Но для постоянной работы у меня, например, есть специальная программа (довольно большая) с кучей разных фич, доступом под одним юзером и переключением на хосте на другого и проч., уже несколько лет удовлетворяющей наши нужды при подобных работах. Но, не думаю, что выкладывать ее тут к месту.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, в принципе `~/.ssh/known_hosts` можно мувнуть, а потом восстановить (думал, автор догадается), хотя, это тоже тот еще костыль.

Comment: повторяю: предложение удалять `~/.ssh/known_hosts` — деструктивно. настоятельно рекомендую ознакомиться с `man scp` на предмет опции `-o` и с `man ssh_config` на предмет опции `UserKnownHostsFile`.

Comment: я один свой комментарий удалил, но, видимо, его стоит повторить (с корректировкой): две причины, почему я не минусую ваш ответ, это: 1. надежда, что вы отредактируете его, хотя бы убрав эту деструктивную команду rm. 2. я не ставил «минусов» с декабря прошлого года, и мне не хотелось бы прерывать эту тенденцию.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, если этот `rm` убрать, то такой скрипт просто не будет работать во всех случаях, а вспоминать tcl, чтобы это обойти неохота. Но, в принципе, я уверен, что можно написать expect-script с условиями.

Comment: расшифровываю свой [комментарий](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540126/540181?noredirect=1#comment682914_540181): `scp -o 'UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null' ...`

Comment: кстати, а как описываемые вами «безопасники упёртого клиента» отнеслись к предложенной вами идее отключить механизм идентификации удалённого хоста?

Comment: С ними это не обсуждали. Впрочем, сейчас это не актуально, поскольку подобные скрипты уже не используются. А вот с UserKnownHostsFile я честно говоря, не так и понял. Что и куда надо положить, чтобы scp/ssh перестали спрашивать пароль? Неужели в файл (/dev/null это шутка?) надо положить host password в открытом виде?

Comment: опция `UserKnownHostsFile` указывает файл, где хранятся идентификаторы известных хостов. по умолчанию это `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. если указать, например, `/dev/null`, то это, фактически, отключит такую идентификацию (но запрос yes/no всё равно будет выводиться). главное — без удаления/переименования актуального файла `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, спасибо. Сейчас поправлю скрипт, а вот проверю уже завтра.

Comment: уточняю: запрос yes/no по поводу верить/не верить хосту, всё равно будет выводиться.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, об этом я догадался (надеюсь верно).

Comment: *а вот проверю уже завтра* — протестируйте тогда уж заодно и опцию `-o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no'` (вместо `-o 'UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null'`). она, насколько помню, будет лишь прервывать выполнение команды при изменении идентификации, а добавлять идентификацию — автоматически.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, UserKnownHostsFile работает, а с StrictHostKeyChecking в скрипте что-то не получилось (естественно, expect и send для yes/no я убирал). Если на след. неделе будет время еще раз вдумчиво попробую

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41969/discussion-on-answer-by-avp-----).